# How to remove only one instance of an object from an NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

The Apple documentation says that the `- (void)removeObject:(id)anObject` method removes all occurrences of the given object from an `NSMutableArray`.

Is there a way to remove only one occurrence of the object from the array?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have a particular instance that you want removed, which has a unique memory address but would otherwise compare equal to other instances, you would use [`removeObjectIdenticalTo:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDDBAG).

If you want to remove the first object in the array that fits the bill, use `indexOfObject:`, which finds the lowest index, followed by `removeObjectAtIndex:` You can also use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` to get the list of all indexes that contain equal objects, as an `NSIndexSet`, and then pick one out from there -- perhaps [`lastIndex`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002197-BAJDDCAC), e.g.

Answer (score 4):

It is really simple:
[yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:[yourArray indexOfObject:yourObject]]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want to find the index of the specific object you want to remove and call:

```
- (void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

See the Apple documentation for NSMutableArray [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABCAFIH).

Comment: Yes I know of this method. However I was looking for a method where I don't need to know the index. Where I only need to provide the actual object to be removed.

Comment: than you have create your own function to delete it.